# How to set another function to closebutton in panorama

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

(sorry for my english) i have a problem,,, I´m trying to create a web in which user click on a polygon and it move user to another page with Google Street View Panorama (this i have). But i also need a code to move user back from "panorama page" to "polygons page" after clicking on close button in panorama. I tried to use the same code like i used before to move user to "panorama page" but it doesn´t work  (it just closes panorama, but doesn´t move back to "polygons page"). The line:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, "closeclick", function(event) { window.location = "index.html"; })
```

is the code to move user back to "polygons page" (index.html). Here is the whole code:

`function initialize() {`

```
var panoOptions = {
 pano: 'Kuchyn',
 enableCloseButton: true,
 pov: {
     heading: 0,
     pitch: 0,
     zoom: 0
     },
 panoProvider: getCustomPanorama,
 visible: true};

var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
 document.getElementById('map-canvas'), panoOptions);

function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
     return 'images/Untitled.jpg';}

function getCustomPanorama(pano, zoom, tileX, tiley) {

if (pano == 'Kuchyn') {
 return {
  location: 
   {pano: 'Kuchyn',
    description: 'Kromeriz - Kuchyn'},

  links: [],
  copyright: 'Oznog (c) 2013',
  Heading: 180,

  tiles: 
   {tileSize: new google.maps.Size(4096, 2048),
    worldSize: new google.maps.Size(4096, 2048),
    centerHeading: 180,
    verticalFOV: 90,
    getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl}
};
}
}
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, "closeclick", function(event) { window.location = "index.html"; })
```

Please help me, Jan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eventListener for panorama is outside `initialize` function, move it under panorama declaration as follows:

```
var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
     document.getElementById('map-canvas'), panoOptions);

// move it here
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, "closeclick", function(event) { window.location = "index.html"; });
```

This is because you are not declaring panorama as a global variable, so it cant be attached correctly. Other option is to declare it as global variable `var panorama;` to above your initialize method.

Cheers.